# Springfox not showing docs

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, swagger

I'm trying to add Swagger to my Spring MVC project. I'm  using this dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is my SwaggerConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .pathMapping("/")
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    @Bean
    public UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
        return UiConfiguration.DEFAULT;
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("My awesome API")
                .description("Some description")
                .version("1.0")
                .contact("my-email@domain.org")
                .build();
    }
}
```

I'm also added resource handlers to register

```
   registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

   registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
```

I've added `@ApiModel(...)` and `@ApiModelProperty(...)` to my model class
My api class is also annotated like below.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@Api(description = "Test")
public class RestServer {

    @ApiOperation(value = "Gets all tags")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/alltags", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Tag> getAllTags() {
        return (List<Tag>) tagRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

I'm getting only
http://localhost:5001/swagger-ui.html

[image]

Comment: Have you tried upgrading `springfox-swagger2` also to 2.3.1?

Comment: yup, but nothing changed.

Comment: My guess is that you have a servlet path mapping that's causing the swagger-ui to not find the right end points. For eg if your context root is /app and your servlet mapping is /api then your swagger ui should ideally be served at /app/api/swagger-ui.html.

Answer (score 1):

I know its too late. But i guess this will help somebody else.

Along with all your above change. Try adding the below changes to your spring-servlet.xml config file.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Swagger config bean -->
<bean class="<---package--->.SwaggerConfig"/>
```